# Duplicate an environment

Tags: environments, abstract

How can I duplicate an environment?

I want to create an environment which is almost exactly equal to another environment. I just want to change the heading.

Right now I use

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
    Thanks
\end{abstract}
```

but I want the exact same output just with

```
\begin{acknowledgements}
    Thanks
\end{acknowledgements}
```

Comment: Do you want to duplicate both the look and the contents of some environment (apart from a change to the header), or do you want to duplicate just the look?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Wanna make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is easily doable with a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
               {\renewcommand*\abstractname{Acknowledgements}‌​\abstract}
               {\endabstract}
```

The commands `\abstract` and `\endabstract` are the macros that are internally used for the `abstract` environment (albeit without the checking of an existing definition).

Depending on the used class and packages in your document it might not be sufficient to redefine the `\abstractname` to get a fully correct outcome (think of adding a Table of Contents entry, different style of page numbering or chapter numbering scheme).